# KUbuntu What is the function of Check and Default Checkboxes on Pin Submenu

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I am used to in pinning application in Windows taskbar.

In Kubuntu when I right click an icon in the panel, there is a option called pin. On its submenu there are few options.

[image]

I understand `On All Activities` and `On the Current Activity`. (Different activities are like different desktops. It is different than the virtual desktop concept. We can create virtual desktops inside Activity. So, I think this is clear.)

However, I do not understand Why the `Check` and `Default` checkboxes are there.

Can anyone please explain?

Comment: How many activities have you set up? What are their names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system, `Default` refers to the default activity, the one that exists by default and can't be deleted. The other entries are the names of other activities I created. It's probable that you have an Activity named `Check`.

[image: Activities listed in alphabetical order in the Pin options]